# Why the same expression (hash2.keep_if { |k, v| k }) return distinct values?

Tags: ruby, hash

Consider the sequence of commands:

```
hash1 = {1 => "a" , 2 => "b" , 3 => "c" , 4 => "d"}
hash2 = {3 => "hello", 4 => "world" , 5 => "welcome"}

hash2.keep_if { |k, v| k }
=> {3=>"hello", 4=>"world", 5=>"welcome"}

hash2.keep_if { |k, v| hash1.key? k }
=> {3=>"hello", 4=>"world"}

hash2.keep_if { |k, v| k }
=> {3=>"hello", 4=>"world"}
```

Why the `hash2.keep_if { |k, v| k }` evaluations are distinct? I would never expect the last result! Why this happen?

Comment: Do note that `keep_if { |k, v| k }` is essentially the same as `keep_if { |k,v| true }`, which means every element will be kept.

Comment: @fylooi, not necessarily: `{ false=>1, nil=>2 }.keep_if { |k,_| k } #=> {}`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Good catch. Didn't know `nil` could be a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classic case of inadvertently using an in-place modifier. [`Hash#keep_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-keep_if) alters the original hash.

```
hash2 = {3 => "hello", 4 => "world" , 5 => "welcome"}

hash2.keep_if { |k, v| k }
# Unmodified since the test does not exclude.

hash2.keep_if { |k, v| hash1.key? k }
# Permanently deletes key `5`

hash2
# => => {3=>"hello", 4=>"world"}
```

Although many in-place modifiers are easy to spot by virtue of including `!` at the end of the name, like `sub!` and `gsub!`, there are a bunch that offer no clue, like `shift` and `pop`. To be certain what effects your call will have, always consult the documentation if you're unfamiliar with the method.

Answer (score 3):

Although not ended with `!`, [`Hash#keep_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-keep_if) is a destructive method, i.e, it modifies the `Hash` object. (See also [`Hash#select!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-select-21))

In your example, `hash2.keep_if { |k, v| hash1.key? k }` removes `5=>"welcome"` part from `hash2`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `hash2` get altered at your second line (courtesy [`keep_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-keep_if)). Here:

```
hash2
# => {3=>"hello", 4=>"world", 5=>"welcome"}
hash2.keep_if { |k, v| hash1.key? k }
# => {3=>"hello", 4=>"world"}

hash2
# => {3=>"hello", 4=>"world"}
```

If you read the official doc for `keep_if`, you can see its states:

> Deletes every element of self for which the given block evaluates to
>   false.

It means `self` itself gets altered. Which then is causing the seen difference in results.